# Is there a way to import Spark AR's example faceDistortionPack.fbx to Blender?

Tags: import, shape-keys, .fbx

I'm trying to edit the faceDistortionPack.fbx, that is used as [an example for Spark AR face deformation.](https://sparkar.facebook.com/ar-studio/learn/documentation/tutorials/face-distortion-and-retouching/#applying-the-blend-shapes) When I import into Blender (2.80), I see the various meshes, I don't see the deformations.

I'm looking under Shape Keys, first of all, and they are empty for each imported objects. I've looked around and there's really nothing like a deformation, just an already deformed mesh...

How do edit this file in Blender to create custom face distortions?

Comment: My guess (without downloading to test) would be to select two face mesh objects  and try F3 "Join as Shapes" operator.  If that works do for all.